# При создании динамического массива Critical error detected c0000374 С++

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, наследование

Возникла проблема при инициализации **динамического** массива

Проблема возникает в строках:

```
int n;
int* arr = new int[n];
```

Изза того что `n` не равна конкретному числу. Как исправить? Вроде нарушений доступа и синтаксиса нет. И почему данная проблема возникла?

*Вот весь код:*

```
class Base 
{
    virtual void Norma() = 0;

};
    class Vector: public Base
    {
        private:
            int n;
            int* arr = new int[n];
        public:
            Vector(){}
           ~Vector(){}
           void InputVector() 
           {
               cout << "Input n:";
               cin >> n;
               for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
               {
                   //arr[i] = rand() % 10;
                   cin >> arr[i];
               }
           }
           void Norma()
           {
               int max=arr[0];
               for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
               {

                   if (arr[i] > max) 
                   {
                       max = arr[i];
                   }

               }
               cout <<"Vector Norma is: "<<fabs(max);
           }
           void OutVector()
           {
               for (int  i = 0; i < n; i++)
               {
                   cout << arr[i] << " ";
               }

           }
    };
    int main()
{



    Vector vec;
    vec.InputVector();
    vec.Norma();
    vec.OutVector();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот просто представьте себя на месте компилятора. И `n` **пусть даже не равно конкретному числу** (хотя на самом деле это не так, оно равно числу, просто вы его не знаете...) - и что должен делать компьютер, встретив такую просьбу? Сколько памяти выделить? Вот как вы себе это представляете? ну просто очень интересно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно часто мне на SO попадается код вроде этого:

```
int n;
int* arr = new int[n];
```

Почему-то новичкам кажется, что `new int[n]` магическим образом связывает `n` с размером массива, так что потом, меняя `n`, можно растягивать и сжимать массив. Это не так. После вызова `new int[n]` размер массива остается фиксированным.

Так что нужно сначала получить `n`, а только потом делать `new`.

Решение: `int* arr = new int[n];` заменить на просто `int *arr;`, а после `cin >> n;` поставить `arr = new int[n];`.

---

Кроме того, обратите внимание: Из вашего класса как из решета течет память! В деструкторе не хватает `delete []`, а также недостает копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания.

Советую почитать: [*правило трех*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (*the rule of three*).

Comment: Автор вопроса, видимо, не совсем понимает, как в целом работает инициализация полей класса в месте их объявления. Думаю, стоит дополнить ответ, чтобы не плодить еще один похожий ответ, вынести new в конструктор, к примеру.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker В конструктор не получится, у него `n` становится известно только в `InputVector`... А засунуть `new` в `InputVector` - это у меня уже написано. :)

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, что конструктора нет, вместо него используется отдельный метод, ну, можно научить человека и этому :)

Answer (score 3):

А чему равно Ваше `n` при создании объекта, не пробовали вывести? Уверен там какой-то мусор. Логичнее задавать это число в конструкторе или инициализировать его после создания экземпляра класса. Вы же выделяете память под неопределённое число элементов, и только потом это число задаёте.