# Как мне создать в массив студентов динамический массив оценок.

Tags: c++

Во код:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Student {

private:

    //string *st;
    /*int n;
    string student[10];
    int n = 10;
    int *ege = new int[n];
    */
    string student;
    int n;
    int *Evaluation;
    int size;

public:

    Student() {
        this->size = 0;
        int *ege = new int[size];
        const int n = 10;
        string student[n];
    }




    ~Student() { cout << "Destruktor is working" << endl; }


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, сталкер смотри сюда [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876569/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-critical-error-detected-c0000374-%D0%A1)

```
class Student {

private:


    int *ege ;

public:

    Student(int size) {

        this->ege = new int[size];
         for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
           cin>>ege[i];
         }

    }

    ~Student() { cout << "Destruktor is working" << endl; }

};
```